# QTransform Class and Evaluating/Reading Matrices

Tags: qt, matrix, qgraphicsview

Using `QGraphicsView::transform()` returns the current transformation matrix, `QTransform`.
 Is there a way to read the values from this matrix as if you were reading them from an array?
 I'm using `scale()` and a horizontal slider right now, but for this to work correctly I believe I have to use the current `X/YScalingFactor` to account for how much the image has already been scaled. Anyone know how to read values from the 3x3 transformation matrix given by using `transform()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can just use static function variables to keep track of the changes to my scale, so this question is partially answered. I am still curious about reading the matrices though